# What does it mean two vectors reciprocally perpendicular?

Tags: vectors

If I have two vectors $\vec a$=(x,y,z) and $\vec b$=($x_1$,$y_1$,$z_1$) by reciprocally perpendicular does it mean  ($\frac1x$,$\frac1y$,$\frac1z$) * ($\frac1x_1$,$\frac1y_1$,$\frac1z_1$) = 0 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never encoutered this definition, maybe it is a rendundant mode to simply say that they are $mutually$ perpendicular, that is obvious since orthogonality for vectors is a reflexive property.

Comment: I was confused aswell , thank you

Comment: @HikenNoAce Wait just a minute for some other comments, maybe someone has some different point of view!

Comment: Ok thank you I will wait

Comment: @HikenNoAce Just a few minutes are sufficient here, when you make a mistake the downvotes come suddenly!

Comment: yes I am getting used to it xd